# Iterating a ResultSet using the JDBC for Oracle takes a lot of time about 16s?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
while( result_set.next() )
{
  ...
}
```

I have use `System.nanoTime()` and calculated the time, for each iteration the time taken is in milliseconds but the overall loop takes about 16s. I am considering a possible reason that the condition test is taking a lot of time, the `next()` function.

FYI I am connecting to a remote database server and the select query that I make is completed in milliseconds again calculated using the above mentioned method. 
Any reasons about why it's happening and how I can bring the time to iterate the resultset down to at max a second?

**EDIT:**

I am dealing with about 4000 records and each record contians about 10 columns each having a size of about 10 chars

**EDIT2**
Thanks setFetchsize() did the magic, awesome, awesome

Comment: How many records do you think you have?

Comment: How many records does the result set contains? Also, it will be helpful to understand if the whole code of while loop is provided.

Comment: Either you have a lot of records or you have a slow network. Don't blame JDBC here.

Comment: Profile the ... too. Check for logging on database level.

Comment: What is your `fetchSize` set to? If you haven't explicitly called `preparedStatement.setFetchSize()` you may have a small default; the difference between 4000 fetches of one row at a time, and a single fetch of 4000 rows in one go, could be considerable. Something in between is probably more appropriate though, to avoid using too many resources - maybe 100? That doesn't affect how you handle the result set, just what it's doing in the background.

Comment: 4000 iterations can take any amount of time from near zero to eternity, depending on what you do in the loop.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to change ResultSet fetch size. By default, Oracle JDBC driver receives the result set only 10 rows at a time from the database cursor. It may not significantly improve performance but there arent many other options to make driver work faster.

Comment: `I dont think this will significantly improve performance` - well, it does :-) see my answer below. Anyway +1 for correct and good answer

Answer (score 35):

I have set up a table with 4000 rows and 10 columns with 10 characters each and made a simple performance test using the following approach (`RealTimeCounter` is a class which measures the real time between `start()` and `stop()`):

```
List<String> myResult = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Performance");

RealTimeCounter rtc = new RealTimeCounter();
rtc.start();
while(rs.next()) {
    myResult.add(rs.getString(1));
}
rtc.stop();
System.out.println(rtc);
```

**Results:**

- Default fetch size: execution time is approx. **20 sec**
- fetch size = 100: execution time is approx **2.2 sec**
- fetch size = 500: execution time is approx **450 msec**
- fetch size = 2000: execution time is approx **120 msec**
- fetch size = 4000: execution time is approx **50 msec**
- fetch size = 4001: execution time is approx **10 msec** (!!)

So, the fetch size **does** have a significant impact on the execution speed.

---

Note that, on the other hand, the fetch size has some impact on memory consumption. Interestingly enough, a quick analysis using `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();` before and after the above code showed that the impact is much less than I would expect, though. The numbers I got are:

- Default fetch size: 665k
- fetch size = 100: 665k
- fetch size = 500: 665k
- fetch size = 2000: 743k
- fetch size = 4000: 821k
- fetch size = 4001: 861k

Comment: It's worth mentioning that while increasing fetch size often improves execution speed, it also causes your program to use more memory - you are ultimately making a tradeoff. No free lunches here.

Comment: @JohnRoberts good point - interestingly enough, a quick and dirty analysis of memory consumption showed that the impact is much less than I would expect, though ...